# problems with deploying web app to tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, github, bitbucket

I have currently been tasked with creating a tomcat server on AWS and deploying a web application that my co workers have created. Currently I have no real experience with tomcat or development in general(I'm green).

So far I have the tomcat server set up properly, it is accesible and I can deploy a WAR file and view that. My real question is, what is the standard procedure when it comes to hosting a web application on tomcat, is just deploying a WAR file sufficient, or is there a way to have the entire project directory uploaded.

I just need some guidance, I don't know if I am doing this correctly.

Also if time permits, I need to somehow have it set up so that when a new push happens, it automatically updates on the server, currently the team is using Git and source tree to do all of there pulls and pushes. I think that is linked to a bit bucket account.

Thanks everyone, this site has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chef or Puppet to automate the deployment. Chef

However if you are not much familiar with the whole AWS management. A good place to start is looking at AWS OpWorks. Basically you will just define configuration of various layers and OpWorks takes care of all with whole deployment and configuration. It also AutoScales the application.[OpWorks Tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/). [Deploy on AWS](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/gettingstarted/latest/awsgsg-deploy.pdf)